# Debugging GDK with breakpoints

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm experimenting few GDK samples and developed my own GDK app. But having trouble to debug it. Right now I'm left with only log.d option to monitor the logs while testing it with connected glass device. Is there any other way to debug GDK app in eclipse? like step by step..

Comment: Try my answer here.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574658/how-to-debug-google-glass-gdk-application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574658/how-to-debug-google-glass-gdk-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging with GDK is the same way you would debug a normal android app. Start here http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Answer (score 2):

[Debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html) is the same as in Android all you need to change is that in the manifest file there would be a Launcher Command in intent-filter commented

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Uncomment it for the activity and then you are good to go for Debugging