# Unable to debug glassware- Google glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am unable to debug glassware.I have tried the solution in this thread [How to debug Google Glass GDK application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574658/how-to-debug-google-glass-gdk-application)
This application uses voice commands, It gets installed but doesn't start the default activity.I am unable to find any classes to select in the run configurations.But messages are logged in Log cat.

Update:By activating DDMS I am able to debug.. But its strange that after few times of debugging, app stops working .. I dont get any exceptions logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally don't setup a default activity for Glass since there's not a way to "run" a specific application. You will likely want to set up a voice command and add a listener for that voice command. This is how your application will launch.

Even with no exceptions, could you post your LogCat output? This might help to shed a little more light on the issues you're having. I've been able to debug applications without any issues, so I know it's possible.